# C# - Update several inventory with one button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a `GridView` that shows all the products that my customer is trying to buy. I want to deduct all the products from my inventory with one DELIVER ALL button. What is the best way to do it?

gvOrderDetails (sample table)

```
Order # || Product ID || Product Name  || Quantity || DELIVER Buttons

   1    ||     1      || Sample Item 1 ||    10    || DELIVER

   1    ||     2      || Sample Item 2 ||    20    || DELIVER

   1    ||     3      || Sample Item 3 ||    30    || DELIVER
```

Below is my code for the DELIVER button on the `GridView`

```
void DeductFromInventory()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET Quantity = Quantity - " + gvOrderDetails.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + " WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", gvOrderDetails.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

protected void gvOrderDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeductFromInventory();
}
```

Comment: You're deducting from inventory every time the user selects a different row?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click event of your button

1. Add a checkbox column to your gridview.
2. Pass the gridview data to a datatable.
3. Scan the datatable [eg. use a loop] to filter if checkbox is checked [bool/bit]
4. Update if checked, don't if not checked.